# Firebase android auth state listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase in my android app. I want to update the Email Address of user. For this, I'm using

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateEmail()
```

Which is updating the user email successfully and `FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener` is called because the token is refreshed. When email-address is updated, Firebase sends an email that your email address has been updated and that email contains the link to reset the email-address back to previous.When the user clicks on that link email-address of the user is restored but there is no callback in Android app.

Firebase auth current user returns the old email address, not the updated one. Is there any solution to that? I have read that we can customize the link %link% in Firebase for sending emails. But for that I have to create a link which must handle all functionality of updating email, updating password etc.

Also, there is no cloud function related to firebase auth When a user is updated. The only available functions are **OnWrite** and **onDelete**

Comment: Have you tried to logout the current user, and then login again with the new email?

Comment: Or in addition to @COLD ICE response,  you can check the auth state in the onStart() so that the new email is refreshed

Comment: @COLD ICE yes, the we have the updated email but my question is what about the existing session.